# Why am I getting a syntax error?

Tags: php

Why is this php statement `$var1 += & $var2` wrong?
**response to comments**: i'm using it to store a smart database query, in fact $var2 is my database connection, i can't drop the reference because it would mean making too many copies of my database, as for the bitwise response `&=` will do the increment also?

Comment: What is your ultimate goal from executing this statement? IE: What do you expect to see as the result?

Comment: Wrong in what sense? What error does it give you? What output does it give you? What did you want it to do? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: are you trying to do pointer arithmetic in a language that only supports weak references? Or what is this?

Comment: @Dominic: The error is a syntax error....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to dissapoint you, but the correct answer to my problem was that my connection was returning an array, and the operation was not allowed. Sorry for not sharing all my code, that must have misguided you...

Answer (score 6):

`&`, in the context of your statement, is the [*reference operator*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php).

From the manual:

> References in PHP are a means to access the same variable content by different names. They are not like C pointers; for instance, you cannot perform pointer arithmetic using them, they are not actual memory addresses, and so on. Instead, they are symbol table aliases. Note that in PHP, variable name and variable content are different, so the same content can have different names.

You cannot add a reference to something, which is why your code isn't working.

Since `&` has two meanings in PHP depending, and it is unclear from your question, here are two possibilities for fixing your code, depending on what you were trying to do.

1. If you wanted to add the value of a reference to `$var1`:

   ```
   $var2 = &$reference; // whatever it's supposed to be a reference to
   $var1 += $var2;
   ```
2. If you wanted to shortcut a [bitwise and](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php):

   ```
   $var1 &= $var2;
   ```

Comment: Sort of correct, the `&` is also a `bitwise operator` however. http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Comment: @Brad true, but I believe that PHP needs to find it between two operands to consider it a bitwise and instead of a reference. Of course, as it's just a syntax error in any case, it's a moot point.

Comment: Yea, I get ya there. The real issue is that we just need more information from the OP :) As he may have been wanting a bitwise operator and for whatever reason used the `+=` to try and shortcut it, or he just wanted to reference it, dunno.

Comment: i've tried a variant of the first solution , like this $var1 = & $var4 ; $var2 = & $var3; $var = $var1 + $var2; and still got an error, but it passed the IDE test

Answer (score 0):

The `&` means to pass a variable by reference.  It's used in function signatures.

Also, this just gives a syntax error.

Comment: In this case, since its not next to the variable, the & is a binary operation

Comment: @MANCHUCK: Well in this case PHP would see it as a reference, even if it isn't intended as one. +1 to undo someones -1.

Comment: Actually, in this case PHP does not see it being anything valid, the error returned from that statement executing is: `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '&' in php shell code on line 1` So basically it sees it as an unexpected & in code with no directive.

Comment: Sure. Still, logically it belongs to the right hand var and thus denotes a reference. It doesn't belong to the operation. In other languages like C this code probably would work.

Comment: @nickc if you read the manual, you will see that the & is a binary and operator: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php and also used to pass a variable by reference when used in a function.

Comment: @MANCHUCK: Sure, I know that. But in this context it is a reference, not a binary operation ;)

Comment: @nickc since there is a space after & it would be treated as the bitwise operator. "&$var1" is different from "& $var1"

Comment: This has really lowered my confidence in information I get from stackoverflow.

Answer (score -3):

You have two operators next to each other try:

```
$var1 = $var1 + ($var1 & $var2)
```

Comment: -1 for downvoting other peoples post only because you think that your alternative interpretation is better.